# How to fetch GlobalValueSet values in Apex

Tags: apex, global-picklist

There is a global value set that we need to fetch in the Apex class. There are some solutions which are using REST call to Tooling API for accessing them.

However, I want to know, is it possible to fetch GlobalValueSet in Apex without REST call?

It could be either using SOQL or some other way.

**SOQL Query:**
`SELECT Metadata FROM GlobalValueSet WHERE DeveloperName = 'Talent_Role'`

[image: GlobalValueSet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're global value set is being used as a value set for a picklist, you can retrieve it by getting the picklist values for that field.

To do that you use the following:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = ObjectAPIName.FieldAPIName.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was trying to fetch GlobalValueSet values directly which requires tooling API. Thanks